# What is the protocol on handling back and forth messages with shared memory?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

I am learning about shared memory in C, on Linux, and I couldn't find another thread clearing up my doubt, so...

I have set up a shared memory between two processes, sharing the segment address, and have exchanged one round of data. Now I wish to send another string, should the receiving process detach and reattach to get the "updated" message?

This is an example of what I mean:
I have two processes, A and B, and I have to send a string to B, but then I have to send another.

Process A

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char msg[] = "Hello hello";

    int shmid = shmget(100, 1024, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | IPC_CREAT);
    char *shmaddr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    strcpy(shmaddr, argv[1]);

    // Now process B sets up and links to the same address, and prints the message succesfully
    
    shmaddr = msg; // This updates the message on process A, but not on process B
```

How to send the msg[] string across now? Is detaching and reattaching a suboptimal choice? Is there another way I am not aware of?

Comment: Pipes are better suited for a message passing protocol. See here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html.

Comment: `shmaddr = msg;` I hope you're detaching the shared memory before doing that

Comment: And sounds like you should be using message queues instead.

Comment: I am aware of FIFOs and message queues, but the exercise I am doing requires me to use shared memory, hence my question on this specific topic

Comment: you need to copy the message to the shared memory and then tell the other process that it is present. probably look at memory barriers and queue data structures.

Comment: That only works the first time, but how do I do it again? @Shawn implied I should detach and reattach at every consecutive use of the same segment, I'm waiting to see if that's the consensus :)

Comment: I didn't say that; but you shouldn't assign a new value to the variable holding a pointer to the shared memory without releasing it first unless you like memory leaks.

Comment: Got it! So if you didn't say to attach and detach every time what should I do? I still don't know